# Request.Files on Javascript Form Submition

Tags: javascript, file-upload

i have a problem because im working with files, and my boss told me that he didnt want ugly jquery ui popups ( i used them to put an form with enctype to send it to an action with a httppostbasefile  so this isnt an option it has to be async).

so a coworwer i came up with this implementation

[image]

thats a table with a dynamic input file generation, and we have a javascript for submition.

```
var doc = document.createElement('FORM');
doc.style.top = '-3333333333px';
doc.style.display = 'none';
doc.method = 'post';
doc.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';

if (obj.cloned) {
    obj.cloned.name = obj.cloned.id = 'File';
    doc.appendChild(obj.cloned);
    //debugger;
}
doc.action = '../controller/action';
doc.id = "TEMPFORMFORSAVE";
document.body.appendChild(doc);
$(doc).submit();
```

magically this works with chrome and IE 10,

but it doesn't work with IE8 ( im not supprised ) 
please i need to retrieve this file. any idea if IE 8 works diferently on IE 10 on this one?

Comment: IE8 will not support doing anything out of the ordinary with files - your javascript can't read anything about the file, and you can't submit via AJAX. Your options are either a plugin (Flash/Silverlight/Java), or an IFRAME. There are plenty of 3rd party solutions out there, so you may want to look into one of those  if you need anything fancy. Otherwise a simple IFRAME is pretty easy to put together, and it may seem to behave like AJAX to the user, even though it's not.

Comment: im workin an approach with this http://cmlenz.github.io/jquery-iframe-transport/ library